# Java Servlet DB Query with Ajax - slow query time and querystring not always fully passed to the servlet

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to create a AJAX based SQL query with Java EE and Servlets. I'm using Glassfish 3.01 and MS SQL server with Jquery on the client side. 
I put everything together, and bind my ajax function to the textfield's onkeyup event. But sometimes When I put 'teststring' into the textbox only "teststrin" passed to the Servlet. So basically the last char disappears and therefore the query result is not correct.
Not to mention when the resultset contains large amount of data the query is pretty slow. Could you please check if I'm doing something wrong on the server and client side?

On the client side I have this JQuery function:

```
  function ajaxSearch(sstring) {
```

if (sstring.length < 3)
  {
      $("#external").html("

at least 3 chars please....

")
  }
  else
  {
    $('#loading').ajaxStart(function() {
      $(this).show()
      $("#external").hide()
    });

```
$('#loading').ajaxComplete(function() {
  $(this).hide()
  $("#external").show()
});

$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "/myApp/getStd",
    dataType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: "sstring="+escape(sstring),
            async: true,
    success: function(data){
        $("#external").html(data);

    }
 })
```

}
}

On the server side I have this:

@WebServlet(name="getStd", urlPatterns={"/getStd"})
    public class getStd extends HttpServlet {
   @Override
   public void doGet (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws           ServletException, IOException {
            Connection conn = null;
            Statement stmt = null;  
            ResultSet rs = null;
            ArrayList rows = new ArrayList();
            res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            res.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out =  res.getWriter();
            String sql=null;
            String test= req.getParameter("sstring");
    try{
            InitialContext cxt = new InitialContext();
            if (cxt == null) {
             throw new Exception("Uh oh -- no context!");}
           DataSource ds = (DataSource) cxt.lookup( "jdbc/Sample" );
           conn = ds.getConnection();
           stmt = conn.createStatement();
           sql="Select * from MYDB.dbo.testdb where myField like '%"+req.getParameter("sstring")+"%';";
           rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

           while(rs.next()){
            stdRecord cols = new stdRecord();
            cols.setTeljel(rs.getString("Field1"));
            cols.setTitle(rs.getString("Field2"));
            cols.setICS(rs.getString("Field3"));
            cols.setREF(rs.getString("Field4"));
            rows.add(cols);
           }

           req.setAttribute("std", rows);
           req.setAttribute("query",test );
           req.getRequestDispatcher("/showRes.jsp").forward(req, res);
           // close everything to free up resources
           rs.close();
           rs = null;
           stmt.close();
           stmt = null;
           conn.close(); /
           conn = null;  
           rows=null;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(out);
       } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
              try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { ; }
              rs = null;
    }
           if (stmt != null) {
            try { stmt.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { ; }
            stmt = null;
    }
          if (conn != null) {
           try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { ; }
           conn = null;
    }

       }
    }
  }

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the lag in keyup, I think this is related to the performance issue, so let's fix that first and then review afterwards.

As to the performance, you've given very little information about your setup, but two common solutions which are often overlooked by starters are the following:

1. Use a connection pooled `DataSource` instead of `DriverManager`. This saves the cost of connecting the DB on every query (which can take over 200ms while a pooled connection is returned in no-time). Consult the JNDI resource config documentation of the application server in question for details (hint: [admin console](http://blogs.oracle.com/JagadishPrasath/entry/creating_jdbc_connection_pool_resource)).
2. Limit the resultset size in SQL side instead of in Java side. This saves the cost of transferring irrelevant data over network. Just return the top 10 results or something instead of the entire table. Consult the SQL manual of the database in question for details (hint: `SET ROWCOUNT`).

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I'm pretty sure I'm using a connection pooled DataSource with the JTDS driver. I googled around and lots of experts recommended this over the official microsoft one, but I'm not sure. As for your second hint yes I plan to implement that. Right now I'm off of my test environment but tomorrow I'll doublecheck my connection pool and driver settings. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: Hi! I checked and I'm sure that I'm using a connection pooled DataSource. I also changed my sql queries with SET ROWCOUNT and I'm using preparedstatements. But compared to a regular asp ajax request this seems laggy. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you measure what part consumes the most time? Javascript request processing? HTTP connection? HTTP request? DB connection? SQL request? SQL response processing? HTTP response processing? Javascript response processing?

Comment: Any idea how to measure. I'm using this sql - which is also pretty slow...  public static final String SQLJELZET="SET ROWCOUNT ? SELECT  * FROM   (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY ref DESC)   AS Row, * FROM  dbname.dbo.tbalename where title like ?)    AS t2 WHERE  Row >= ? AND Row <= ?";